# Matplotlib: plot triangles with colors associated to the points

Tags: matplotlib

I am working with Matplotlib and must plot a triangular mesh, where the points have associated colors at the vertices. The mesh must be in two dimensions, nothing three-dimensional, which rules all trisurf examples that I have seen.

```
x - x coordiantes of my points 
y - y coordiantes of my points 
s - values associated with my points (should be colors)
triangles - a list of indices [i,j,k] that indicates the triangles.
```

Can you provide an example that, assuming the above data are given, produces a two-dimensional mesh of triangles (with or without coordinate axis displayed) and shades the triangles in accordance to the vertices? It would be great if the wireframe would still be visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called [gouraud shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouraud_shading), and available a.o. by matplotlib's [`tripcolor()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tripcolor.html). In matplotlib this is only supported for colors as values in a given colormap. It is not a full rgb smoothing. For example [`tricontourf()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tricontourf.html) uses this to interpolate color values.

Here is a simple example.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as tri

x = [1, 1, -1, -1, 0]
y = [1, -1, -1, 1, 0]
s = [0.1, 0.75, 0.0, 0.9, 1]
triangles = [[4, 0, 1], [4, 1, 2], [4, 2, 3], [4, 3, 0]]
triang = tri.Triangulation(x, y, triangles)

cmap = plt.cm.rainbow
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 5))

ax1.triplot(triang, lw=2, zorder=0) # draw the outlines of the triangles
ax1.scatter(x, y, c=s, cmap=cmap, s=500) # show the colors of the points

ax2.tripcolor(triang, s, cmap=cmap, shading='gouraud')

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]